# Js html import/export

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I've got 3 files:
index html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
   </head>
   <body>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/dtms.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

And 2 js files:

module:

```
 export const gg = ['123', '2343', '323'];
```

main js:

```
 import {gg} from "/path/main.js";
```

And I am getting error in chrome debugging console:
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

How to fix?

Comment: <script type="module" src="path/to/file.js"></script>
but take in mind that not all browser support modules yet,
see https://caniuse.com/#search=module

Comment: some further infos to previous comment https://blog.whatwg.org/js-modules

Comment: @Yurii, so the only way is to use smth like require js to import and export modules?

Comment: @I.Gursky it depends on what you need. If you need to load each of your js modules asynchronously then yes AMD (require.js, system.js etc) could be used. But it doesn't mean you need to write your code in an old boring AMD way like define('module', [dep1, dep2], function() { /*code*/ }). You can use some tools that convert es6 code to es5+AMD style. For example, you could use webpack+babel pair. But don't know why you may need this. Even with http2 you probably need to bundle your modules into one/few files.

Answer (score 2):

It works here: here https://plnkr.co/edit/3Fy4J3PyvSOBn1avMvg4?p=preview

// Supported:

```
import {foo} from 'https://jakearchibald.com/utils/bar.js';
import {foo} from '/utils/bar.js';
import {foo} from './bar.js';
import {foo} from '../bar.js';
```

// Not supported:

```
import {foo} from 'bar.js';
import {foo} from 'utils/bar.js';
```