# Error: "Unexpected token '{'. Import call expects exactly one argument" when trying to import functions from a script

Tags: javascript, import, safari, importerror

I have set up a html page that contains a button that when clicked, activates a function from an external javascript file. The JS file in question imports two other functions from another JS file. However when I load the html file in my browser (Safari 12.0.2) and look at it in the debugger, I get an error stating "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument."

The files are named "html_test_run.html", "test_run_javascript.js" and "export_test_run.js". I have tried setting the type of the script to "module" but that only resulted in a new error that said "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". I have also attempted to have three html tags, the first two had the source of the js files and the third defined a new function that the button would use instead, that didn't work either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Test run</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Test run">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!--
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/test_run_javascript.js">
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <button type="button" name="button" onclick="doSomething()">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

First JS file:

```
import {doSomethingElse1, doSomethingElse2} from "export_test_run.js";
function doSomething(){
  doSomethingElse1();
  doSomethingElse2();
  console.log("Test successful");
}
```

Second JS file:

```
function doSomethingElse1(){
  console.log("Test successful1");
}

function doSomethingElse2(){
  console.log("Test successful2");
}

export {doSomethingElse1, doSomethingElse2};
```

I expected the files would load correctly and the button would call the function "doSomething()" when clicked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48754177/js-html-import-export

Comment: @RichardSocker Thanks, but when I tried following the example and putting type="module" in the script tag and adding "./" in front of "export_test_run.js" and "assets/test_run_javascript.js" in the files test_run_javascript and html_test_run.html, respectively, I now get the error "Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin". Also I forget to mention that all of the files are on my HD, just in case that's causing the problem.

Comment: @RichardSocker I would be interested in your suggestion. The reason that I use tow Javascript files is that the second file, "export_test_run.js", is a library (sort of) that contains functions that the file "test_run_javascript.js" (and eventually several other JS files) make use of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the two of your js files in the first page:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="export_test_run.js">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/test_run_javascript.js">
  </script>
```

Remove the export and import code from your js files!
Use the correct paths for the including.

Answer (score 5):

You have to correctly include a script on your page showing that the script type is "module":

```
<script src="/js/index.js" type="module"></script>
```

In case if the browser doesn't support modules you can simply process that using "nomodule" attribute:

```
<script nomodule>
  console.info(`Your browser doesn't support native JavaScript modules.`);
</script>
```

Comment: And when starting a web worker, pass in `type: 'module'` to its options: `new Worker('path.js', {type: 'module'})`