# JS import fails, despite following every previous answer to similar questions

Tags: javascript, ajax, import, syntax-error

I know similar questions have been asked a lot, however none of their answers have worked for me. I have two `js` files :

`/js/ajax.js` :

```js
export function ajax(url, content, callback, errorCallback) {
  const httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
    try {
      if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        const response = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
        if (httpRequest.status === 200) {
          callback(response);
        } else {
          errorCallback(response);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  };
  httpRequest.open("POST", url);
  httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpRequest.overrideMimeType("application/json");
  httpRequest.send(JSON.stringify(content));
}
```

`register.js` :

```js
import { ajax } from "./js/ajax.js";

const usernameInput = document.querySelector("#register #username");
const passwordInput1 = document.querySelector("#register #password1");
const passwordInput2 = document.querySelector("#register #password2");
passwordInput2.addEventListener("keydown", identicalPassword, false);

function registerFail(response) {
  usernameInput.value = "";
  passwordInput1.value = "";
  passwordInput2.value = "";
  alert(response.error_message);
}

function registerSuccess() {
  alert("Success, please log in");
  window.location.assign("login.html");
}

function tryRegister() {
  ajax(
    "php/register.php",
    {
      username: usernameInput.value,
      password1: passwordInput1.value,
      password2: passwordInput2.value,
    },
    registerSuccess,
    registerFail
  );
}
```

They are both imported in `register.html` :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Register</title>
  </head>
  <body>
//[...]
    <script src="/js/ajax.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="register.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This results in the error
`[Error] SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'. import call expects one or two arguments.` which, as far as other answers here have told me, *should not* be happening : I'm importing by name, a function that is exported, with the correct path, from a script that is included as a module in the html. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: "Unexpected token '{'. Import call expects exactly one argument" when trying to import functions from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392611/error-unexpected-token-import-call-expects-exactly-one-argument-when-try)

Comment: @Wongjin I don't see anything I'm not already doing in this other question

Comment: @ice-wind You have not set `type=module` on `<script src="register.js"></script>`

Comment: @Yogi Oh, is that a problem ? I thought only the import**ed** files needed to be tagged as modules

Answer (score 0):

I think is not allow use ES6 keywords in browser, if you want to use 'import', you need add 'module' in scripct tags, ex:

```
 <script src="/js/ajax.js" type="module"></script>
 <script src="register.js" type="module"></script>
```

Comment: Do I need to make **both** scripts modules ? I thought only the one that exports needed to be tagged as a module